# UIAlertController and stacked UIAlert Buttons

Tags: xcode, swift, button, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have an Xcode project programmed in Swift.  I have an alert variable:

[image]

I also have the actual code for when the alert appears:

[image]

When I click on the 'Yes' button, everything resets and I can play the game again. 
[image]

If I want to play again and win, the alert now has stacked buttons.
[image]

How do I get rid of that and make it appear like the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't keep adding new actions to your alert box.

Either create a new alert box, or use a flag to indicate you've already created the options, so you don't add them again.

It's turning into the vertical list ("Action Sheet") format, because it now thinks there are four entries and there's not enough room to add them horizontally.  But two of them have blank labels, because it's not letting you duplicate the text, to avoid ambiguity for the end user.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Swift.  How would I add a flag and where?

Comment: @ChallengerGuy I haven't seen how your code is laid out in the bigger picture, for example, when you create the alert itself vs. when you add the buttons .  In a case like this one would typically create a Bool (outside of  any function so it is persistent), initialize it false and check to see if it's set before adding the buttons.  If not set, add the buttons and set it, so they don't get set again. Alternatively, if the operation is cheap enough in terms of CPU time, you could just re-create the alert box when  you add the actions and let the memory management clean up the old one.